# Enable checkbox by checking radio-button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I enable all checkboxes by checking a radio button using jquery?
Basically, if email is checked, all checkboxes can stay disabled, if phone is checked, all checkboxes should enable.

```js
$("input:radio[value=Phone]").on("change", function() {
  $("#chekbox").find("input").prop("enabled", !$("input:radio[value=Email]").prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>
</div>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are no props called "enabled" Also with 1K rep, you should be able to make a [mcve] yourself using the snippet editor

Comment: Voting to close as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm a python guy trying to do some quick things in jquery. It isn't something I'm going to be using a lot. I scanned though the documentation and forgot some things.

Comment: `$("[name=pref]").on("change", function() {
  $(".checkbox [type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", $(this).val() == "Email");
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) for this, because `disable` is attribute not property

Working snippet:-

```js
$("input[name=pref]").on("change", function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", $(this).val()=='Email');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:-*** I have added code like if phone radio button is clicked, check-boxes get enabled and if email radio button is clicked then check-boxes get disabled.

Comment: hmm nice one line

Comment: `!($(this).val()=='Phone')` works the same as `this.value=="Email"`

Comment: @mplungjan  yes, than make solution even shorter and readable too, edited that. Thanks

Comment: As of jQuery >= 1.6, DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input[name=pref]").on("change", function() {
  if(this.value === "Phone"){
      $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");

  } else if (this.value === "Email") {
     $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", true);
    
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
    <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>
  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
</div>
</div>
```

You can use this script.

Comment: No need of that much code. check mine for better one.BTW your answer is correct

Comment: Sure. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```js
$("input:radio[name=pref]").on("change", function() {
  var IsPhone = $('input:radio[value=Phone]').is(':checked') ? true : false;
  $('.checkbox').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', !IsPhone);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var IsPhone = $('input:radio[value=Phone]').is(':checked') ? true : false;` and then `!isPhone` can be coded using `prop('disabled',this.value=="Email")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.radio input[type="radio"]').on('input',function(){

let inputs=$('.radio input[type="checkbox"]');
$(this).val() == 'Phone' ? inputs.attr('disabled',true) : inputs.removeAttr('disabled');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below logic,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:radio[value=Phone]").on("change", function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
  });

  $("input:radio[value=Email]").on("change", function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref" > Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref" > Email </label>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled > Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled > Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled > Evening</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest working code. Note this uses selectors that are less ambiguous than other answers

```js
$("[name=pref]").on("change", function() {
  $("[name^=prefchk]").attr("disabled", this.value == "Email");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>Preferred Contact Method: </label>
  <label class="radio-inline ml-5 "><input type="radio" value="Phone" name="pref"> Phone </label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Email" name="pref"> Email </label>


  <label>If phone is checked can we contact you? </label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="morning" disabled> Morning</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="afternoon" disabled> Afternoon</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline  ml-1"><input type="checkbox" name="prefchk[]" value="evening" disabled> Evening</label>
  </div>
</div>
```